# qdPM Symfony 1.4 500 Internal server error - Empty response header name, aborting request

Tags: php, apache, debugging, http-headers, symfony-1.4

I have been using qdPM v9.0 (from qdpm/core/apps/qdPM/config/app.yml) on Centos 6.7 server with PHP 7.0.6 and apache 2.2.x and MariaDB 5.5.x for over a year now without any issues.
It seems to be using legacy Symfony 1.4.

I tried to install Let's Encrypt SSL certificates and this upgraded Apache/httpd to 2.2.15, no change in PHP or MariaDB versions.

Upon restarting httpd after SSL certificate installation, suddenly I get 500 Internal Server Error and the httpd error log shows:

```
...
[Wed Aug 09 14:55:22 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Empty response header name, aborting request
[Wed Aug 09 14:55:32 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Empty response header name, aborting request
...
```

Also, this is not a misconfiguration of SSL/Apache because other apps on other sub-domains continue work fine, both with and without Let's Encrypt SSL certificates.

Google does not help except some German discussion suggests to use PHP 5.3:
https://www.php.de/forum/webentwicklung/php-frameworks/1508593-installation-symfony-framework

> Symfony 1 geht nur mit maximal PHP 5.3... Deswegen sagte ich doch hol dir Symfony 3!!!

I cleared the cache several times.
I removed all Let's Encrypt SSL configuration as well as restored old self-signed SSL certificates and restored Apache configuration to earlier working state.

And because we take backups daily, I even restored the entire code backup from a few hours before.

This should definitely have worked.

I still get the same error and no clue / hint as to how to debug it.
Symfony logging documentation is for its current version, not for 1.4

What could have caused this issue?

How do I enable debugging so I could find where the error "Empty response header name" is being created so that maybe I can patch it?

Answer (score 13):

I modified the function and it works: (php 7.0+)

.../core/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 407

`/**
    * Retrieves a normalized Header.
    *
    * @param  string $name  Header name
    *
    * @return string Normalized header
    */
    protected function normalizeHeaderName($name)
    {
      $out = [];
      array_map(function($record) use (&$out) {
        $out[] = ucfirst(strtolower($record));
      }, explode('-',$name));
      return implode('-',$out);
    }`

Comment: Super old, I know, but this deserves to be the accepted answer Gábor deserves a few points for this

Answer (score 1):

This version works fine too:

```
  /**
   * Retrieves a normalized Header.
   *
   * @param  string $name  Header name
   *
   * @return string Normalized header
   */
  protected function normalizeHeaderName($name)
  {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\-(.)/', function ($matches) { return '-'.strtoupper($matches[1]); }, strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trace down the problem to the sent headers

```
core/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php 
on line 357
```

something is wrong with the values.

qdPM 9.0 was running fine for over a year on PHP7, until an Apache 2 update for Ubuntu 16.04 was coming along.

However, I found the issue:

```
E_WARNING: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in 
.../core/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 409
```

but I do not get the old line:

```
return preg_replace('/\-(.)/e', "'-'.strtoupper('\\1')", strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));
```

converted so that it will work. As far as I understand, it shall replace anything behind a dash with uppercase-letters. But I can't get it to work with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
return preg_replace_callback('\-(.)', function($m) { return '-'.strtoupper($m[1]); } , strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));
```

the anonymous function wont get called at all. I have removed the preg replace completely and now it is working fine. Maybe we will get an update here how to solve it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, I worked around my issue by reverting PHP version from 7.0 to 5.6